# Extracting part of string in parenthesis using python

Tags: python, csv, substring

I have a csv file with a column with strings. Part of the string is in parentheses. I wish to move the part of string in parentheses to a different column and retain the rest of the string as it is.

For instance: I wish to convert:

```
LC(Carbamidomethyl)RLK
```

to

```
LCRLK Carbamidomethyl
```

Comment: Will you have many parentheses in your string? Like L(abc)C(def)FIV to LCFIV abcdef

Comment: No. It only has this one value in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regex solution

If you only have one parentheses group in your string, you can use this regex:

```
>>> a = "LC(Carbamidomethyl)RLK"
>>> re.sub('(.*)\((.+)\)(.*)', '\g<1>\g<3> \g<2>', a)
'LCRLK Carbamidomethyl'
>>> a = "LCRLK"  
>>> re.sub('(.*)\((.+)\)(.*)', '\g<1>\g<3> \g<2>', a)
'LCRLK'  # works with no parentheses too
```

Regex decomposed:

```
(.*)       #! Capture begin of the string
\(         # match first parenthesis
  (.+)     #! Capture content into parentheses
\)         # match the second
(.*)       #! Capture everything after

---------------
\g<1>\g<3> \g<2>  # Write each capture in the correct order
```

## String manipulation solution

A faster solution, for huge data set is:

```
begin, end  = a.find('('), a.find(')')
if begin != -1 and end != -1: 
    a = a[:begin] + a[end+1:] + " " + a[begin+1:end]
```

The process is to get the positions of parentheses (if there's any) and cut the string where we want. Then, we concatenate the result.

## Performance of each method

It's clear that the string manipulation is the fastest method:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.sub('(.*)\((.+)\)(.*)', '\g<1>\g<3> \g<2>', a)", setup="a = 'LC(Carbadidomethyl)RLK'; import re")
15.214869976043701


>>> timeit.timeit("begin, end  = a.find('('), a.find(')') ; b = a[:begin] + a[end+1:] + ' ' + a[begin+1:end]", setup="a = 'LC(Carbamidomethyl)RL'")
1.44008207321167
```

## Multi parentheses set

See comments

```
>>> a = "DRC(Carbamidomethyl)KPVNTFVHESLADVQAVC(Carbamidomethyl)SQKNVACK"
>>> while True:
...     begin, end  = a.find('('), a.find(')')
...     if begin != -1 and end != -1:
...         a = a[:begin] + a[end+1:] + " " + a[begin+1:end]
...     else:
...         break
...
>>> a
'DRCKPVNTFVHESLADVQAVCSQKNVACK Carbamidomethyl Carbamidomethyl'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this out. I need to apply this to a large csv file. I am new to programming and I need to handle large data sets for my research.

Comment: Be aware this solution can be pretty slow due to the use of regex...  I have update my answer with a string manipulation solution which is 10 times faster ;)

Comment: How do I deal with a situation where I have more than one set of parentheses in my string? For example: DRC(Carbamidomethyl)KPVNTFVHESLADVQAVC(Carbamidomethyl)SQKNVACK